# Solve $y(1+2xy)dx+x(1-2xy)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y(1+2xy)dx+x(1-2xy)dy=0$

I tried to solve this for many methods, but is an inexact differential equation and I couldn't find an integrant factor, can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently the result involves the Lambert W-function: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y(1%2B2xy)dx%2Bx(1-2xy)dy%3D0

Comment: Yes, I wonder how Lambert W-functions appears there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My teacher found that if you make $u=xy$, you transform the differential equation into

### $\dfrac{du}{dx}(1-2u)=\dfrac{-4u^2}{x}$

And this D.E. can be solved by separable variables. Then you go back and find that

### $\dfrac{1}{2}log(xy)+\dfrac{1}{4xy}=log(x)+k$

That is the implicit solution of $y(1+2xy)dx+x(1−2xy)dy=0$. I think that if you want to find $y=f(x)$, you have to use Lambert W-function because there are involved some natural logarithms. But this answer is enough for me.